# Github Actions quits without validating after Reboot

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to implement simple github action workflow to ssh to the ec2 instance run yum update, restart, and verify that system is up after the restart. The update part is running fine but when it comes for verifying that the machine is up again it fails with the error

out: No updates available
out: Rebooting the machine...
2023/02/22 20:47:14 wait: remote command exited without exit status or exit signal

that's the steps:

```
steps:
    - name: SSH into VMs
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
        script: |
          if sudo yum check-update; then
            sudo yum update -y
          else
            echo "No updates available"
          fi
          echo "Rebooting the machine..."
          sudo reboot
          sleep 600
    - name: Wait for VMs to come back
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
        script: |
          echo "Running vm to comeback"
          until ping -c1 ${{ secrets.HOST }}; do sleep 1; done
          if ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}@${{ secrets.HOST }} 'exit'; then
            echo "Success: VM is back up and running"
          else
            echo "Error: Failed to connect to the VM"
            exit 1
          fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behaviour is that once `reboot` command is executed your SSH connection to EC2 instance is terminated. As a consequence it results with an error in *SSH into VMs* step.

If you want to reboot EC2 instance via Github Actions you can do it in a separate step with AWS CLI [reboot-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/reboot-instances.html) command.